# using Javascript to calculate and input into html

Tags: javascript, html

The attached screenshot is my output. What I am trying to achieve is when I click `AddWood`, there will be 3 textbox generated (which is fine). the 3 textbox represent name, length and width. Once I hit calculate there should be a display below showing my the area, which is not working. 
Can anyone help to point out where my mistake is?

```js
function addText() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div2");
  div1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id=Wname/><br> <input type='text' id=length/><br>  <input type='text' id=width/>";
}

function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var area = length * width;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = area;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnok" onclick="addText();" value="Add Wood"/>
<br />
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` need to be inside the quotes. Also `input` is a self closing tag

```js
function addText() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div2");
  div1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Wname'/><br> <input type='text' id='length'><br>  <input type='text' id='width'>";
}

function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var area = length * width;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = area;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2"></div>

<input type="button" id="btnok" onclick="addText();" value="Add Wood" />
<br />
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
  <p id="Result"></p>
```

Comment: Great answer but I would like to mention `parseInt()` should be used on those values to avoid `NAN` result. Still **+1**

Answer (score 2):

This line looks wrong to me, no inner quote marks around the `id` values

```
div1.innerHTML="<input type='text' id=Wname/><br> <input type='text' id=length/><br>  <input type='text' id=width/>";
```

Chuck it into a snippet, seems to do the trick.

```js
function addText() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div2");
  div1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Wname' /><br> <input type='text' id='length' /><br>  <input type='text' id='width' />";
}

function myFunction() {
  var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var area = length * width;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = area;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnok" onclick="addText();" value="Add Wood"/>
<br />
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

**Also...**

It might be worth giving a look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ and debugging javascript (similar tools for all major browsers, just google).

Placing a breakpoint or even just some `console.log(blah)`, `console.info(blah)` or `console.error(blah)` calls would be all you need to quickly resolve the vast majority of errors, or at the least provide better framed questions for even better help.